# Trying to query with OR on some related entities and AND on other related entities

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm having some difficulty creating a query where I'm using Or on some related entity fields and And on some other related entity fields. I'm using QueryExpression since that is what I am most familiar with, but if there is a better way to do it, I'm all for it.

Specifically, I'm querying Contracts where either the BillTo.Name or the Customer.Name equal a passed in value, and some custom values on the associated Contract Line are equal to passed in values. This is what I have tried so far. The problem is that it is treating the BillTo name and Customer name with an And operator instead of an Or.

```cs
QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression(Contract.EntityLogicalName);

ColumnSet acctColumns = new ColumnSet("name");
LinkEntity acctlink = new LinkEntity("contract", "account", "customerid", "accountid", JoinOperator.Inner);
acctlink.LinkCriteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
acctlink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, CustName);
acctlink.Columns = acctColumns;
qe.LinkEntities.Add(acctlink);

ColumnSet billToColumns = new ColumnSet("name");
LinkEntity billToLink = new LinkEntity("contract", "account", "billingcustomerid", "accountid", JoinOperator.Inner);
billToLink.LinkCriteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or;
billToLink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("name", ConditionOperator.Equal, CustName);
billToLink.Columns = billToColumns;
qe.LinkEntities.Add(billToLink);

ColumnSet contractColumns = new ColumnSet("expireson");
LinkEntity contractLineLink = new LinkEntity("contract", "contractdetail", "contractid", "contractid", JoinOperator.Inner);
contractLineLink.Columns = contractColumns;

LinkEntity productLink = new LinkEntity("contractdetail", "product", "productid", "productid", JoinOperator.Inner);
productLink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("productnumber", ConditionOperator.Equal, ProductID);
contractLineLink.LinkEntities.Add(productLink);

qe.LinkEntities.Add(contractLineLink);

FilterExpression fe = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
ConditionExpression ceVersion = new ConditionExpression("new_version", ConditionOperator.Equal, versionID);
ConditionExpression ceCust = new ConditionExpression("new_cust", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);
ConditionExpression ceComp = new ConditionExpression("new_comp", ConditionOperator.Like, formattedDBName);

fe.AddCondition(ceVersion);
fe.AddCondition(ceCust);
fe.AddCondition(ceComp);

qe.Criteria.AddFilter(fe);
qe.ColumnSet = cs;

EntityCollection contractDetails = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

**EDIT - Final code**
Here's what I ended up doing after reading through the options that Darin mentioned.

```
        Guid acctGuid = acctRef.Id; //  Retrieve EntityReference in another method
        ColumnSet cs = new ColumnSet();

        QueryExpression qe = new QueryExpression(Contract.EntityLogicalName);

        ColumnSet contractColumns = new ColumnSet("expireson", "new_registrationkey");
        LinkEntity contractLineLink = new LinkEntity("contract", "contractdetail", "contractid", "contractid", JoinOperator.Inner);
        contractLineLink.Columns = contractColumns;

        LinkEntity productLink = new LinkEntity("contractdetail", "product", "productid", "productid", JoinOperator.Inner);
        productLink.LinkCriteria.AddCondition("productnumber", ConditionOperator.Equal, ProductID);
        contractLineLink.LinkEntities.Add(productLink);

        qe.LinkEntities.Add(contractLineLink);

        FilterExpression fe = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.And);
        ConditionExpression ceVersion = new ConditionExpression("new_version", ConditionOperator.Equal, VersionID);
        ConditionExpression ceCust = new ConditionExpression("new_cust", ConditionOperator.Equal, true);
        ConditionExpression ceComp = new ConditionExpression("new_comp", ConditionOperator.Like, formattedName);
        fe.AddCondition(ceVersion);
        fe.AddCondition(ceCust);
        fe.AddCondition(ceComp);

        qe.Criteria.AddFilter(fe);
        qe.ColumnSet = cs;

        FilterExpression fe2 = new FilterExpression(LogicalOperator.Or);
        ConditionExpression ceCustomerName = new ConditionExpression("customerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, acctGuid);
        ConditionExpression ceBillToName = new ConditionExpression("billingcustomerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, acctGuid);
        fe2.AddCondition(ceCustomerName);
        fe2.AddCondition(ceBillToName);
        qe.Criteria.AddFilter(fe2);

        EntityCollection contractDetails = crmService.RetrieveMultiple(qe);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two options

1. Change your `InnerJoin`'s to `LeftOuter`'s, then filter the results on the client side.
2. Perform two separate queries, one with an inner join for the customer id, and one for an inner join for the billing customer id, then combine them on the client side.

The `FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.Or` only works on `ConditionExpression`s within the Filter, and since you're only setting one `ConditionExpression` it doesn't really do anything.

Comment: With this is mind, I updated my query a bit. I had been hoping to avoid an extra trip, but since once of the options relied on it, I decided to make a trip to get the guid of the name passed in, then I could use that to simplify the main query a bit. I'll post the updated code at the end of the main post in case it helps anyone else.